# Binary Search Tree Potentially Uninitiated Parent Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, parent

```
I couldnt seem to resolve the unitialized local pointer "Parent". There isnt any other issue with this code other than the local pointer error I keep receiving  Its driving me insane.
```

this is just me writing to post the simplest of questions
please aide me
  I couldnt seem to resolve the unitialized local pointer "Parent". There isnt any other issue with this code other than the local pointer error I keep receiving  Its driving me insane.

this is just me writing to post the simplest of questions
please aide me

```
//Binary Search Tree
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    class BinarySearchTree
    {
    private:
        struct  tree_node
        {
            tree_node* left;
            tree_node* right;
            int data;
        };

        tree_node* root;

    public:

        BinarySearchTree()
        {
            root = NULL;

        }

        bool IsEmpty() const {
            return root == NULL;
        }
        void print_inorder();
        void inorder(tree_node*);
        void print_preorder();
        void preorder(tree_node*);
        void print_postorder();
        void postorder(tree_node*);
        void insert(int);
        void remove(int);

    };

    void BinarySearchTree::insert(int d)
    {

        tree_node* t = new tree_node;
        tree_node* parent;
        t->data = d;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
        parent = NULL;

        if (IsEmpty()) root = t;
        else
        {
            tree_node* curr;
            curr = root;

            while (curr)
            {
                parent = curr;
                if (t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
                else curr = curr->left;
            }

            if (t->data < parent->data)
                parent->left = t;
            else
                parent->right = t;
        }

    }

    void BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)
    {
        tree_node* curr;
        tree_node* parent;

        bool found= false;

        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            cout << " This Tree is Empty!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        curr = root;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            if (curr->data == d)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                parent = curr;
                if (d > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
                else curr = curr->left;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            cout << " Data is not found!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        if ((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL) || (curr->left != NULL && curr->right == NULL))
        {
            if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right !=NULL)
            {
                if (parent -> left == curr)
                {
                    parent->left = curr->right;
                    delete curr;
                }
                else {
                    parent->right = curr->right;
                    delete curr;
                }
            }
            else //Left child
            {
                if (parent->left == curr)
                {
                    parent->left = curr->left;
                    delete curr;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent->right = curr->left;
                    delete curr;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
        {
            if (parent->left == curr) parent->left = NULL;
            else parent->right = NULL;
            delete curr;
            return;
        }


        //Node with 2 Children
        if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
        {
            tree_node* chkr;
            chkr = curr->right;
            if ((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
            {
                curr = chkr;
                delete chkr;
                curr->right = NULL;
            }
            else
            {

                if ((curr->right)->left != NULL)
                {
                    tree_node* lcurr;
                    tree_node* lcurrp;
                    lcurrp = curr->right;
                    lcurr = (curr->right)->left;

                    while(lcurr ->left != NULL)
                    {
                        lcurrp = lcurr;
                        lcurr = lcurr->left;
                    }
                    curr->data = lcurr->data;
                    delete lcurr;
                    lcurrp->left = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    tree_node* tmp;
                    tmp = curr->right;
                    curr->data = tmp->data;
                    curr->right = tmp->right;
                    delete tmp;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

    }
    void BinarySearchTree::print_inorder()
    {
        inorder(root);
    }
    void BinarySearchTree::inorder(tree_node* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            if (p->left) inorder(p->left);
            cout << " " << p->data << " ";
            if (p->right) inorder(p->right);
        }
        else return;
    }
    void BinarySearchTree::print_preorder()
    {
        preorder(root);
    }
    void BinarySearchTree::preorder(tree_node* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            cout << " " << p->data << " ";
            if (p->left)preorder(p->left);
            if (p->right) preorder(p->right);
        }
        else return;
    }
    void BinarySearchTree::postorder(tree_node* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            if (p->left) postorder(p->left);
            if (p->right) postorder(p->right);
            cout << " " << p->data << " ";
        }
        else return;
    }

    int main()
    {
        BinarySearchTree b;
        int ch, tmp, tmp1;
        while (1)
        {
            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << " Binary Search Tree Operations " << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << " 1. Insertion/Creation " << endl;
            cout << " 2. In-Order Traversal " << endl;
            cout << " 3. Pre-Order Traversal " << endl;
            cout << " 4. Post-Order Traversal " << endl;
            cout << " 5. Removal " << endl;
            cout << " 6. Exit " << endl;
            cout << " Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> ch;

            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1: cout << "Enter Number to be Inserted: ";
                cin >> tmp;
                b.insert(tmp);
                break;
            case 2: cout << endl;
                cout << " In-Order Traversal: " << endl;
                cout << "---------------------" << endl;
                b.print_inorder();
                break;
            case 3: cout << endl;
                cout << " Pre-Order Traversal: " << endl;
                cout << "------------------------" << endl;
                b.print_preorder();
                break;
            case 4: cout << endl;
                cout << " Post-Order Traversal: " << endl;
                cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
                b.print_postorder();
                break;
            case 5: cout << " Enter data to be deleted: ";
                cin >> tmp1;
                b.remove(tmp1);
                break;
            case 6: system("pause");
                return 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your question in an easily readable layout, and clarify what your question is.  Where does the error occur?  What *is* the error?

Comment: within the function BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)

Comment: if ((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL) || (curr->left != NULL && curr->right == NULL))
 {
  if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right !=NULL)
  {
   if (parent -> left == curr)
   {
    parent->left = curr->right;
    delete curr;
   }
   else {
    parent->right = curr->right;
    delete curr;

Comment: if (parent -> left == curr)      is where the error occurs

Comment: I repeat, **what is the error?**

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'parent' used Korszun_Binary_Search_Tree f:\data structures\korszun_portfolio\assignment 6\korszun_binary_search_tree\korszun_binary_search_tree\binary_search_tree.cpp 109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree_node* parent;`

You declare parent but never assign it a `tree_node` memory address to point to.  Thus, performing operations on it or accessing its members (like `parent->left`) will cause issues, and raise the error you are getting.

Solution: Assign a value to parent before accessing it's members.

Comment: That makes sense but where would I assign it to?

Comment: Well, I assume by parent you mean `root`?  I don't know.  It's your code, not mine.

Comment: Im simply checking the pointer to the current value in the array?

Comment: Thanks man. Ill see what I'm able to do. I should have added a few more comment lines. Im getting lost in it.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.  Well done.